# Debugging a firebase auth app from vscode and chrome not working

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, firebase-authentication

I have a web app (angular) that uses firebase authentication with the google login provider.   On windows, when I use vscode attaching to chrome in debug mode to the app running on localhost:4200, I get the following message when I attempt to login with a google account in the popup after entering my google credentials:

```
Couldn't sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure.
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.
```

The app works and logs in successfully if I don't have vscode launch chrome in debug mode but instead just launch chrome from the start menu and point it at localhost:4200.  Additionally, I can successfully use the built in chrome debugger on the site when launched in this manner.

I get the same issue on the new edge based on chromium as well; but didn't get it on old edge.

I'm wondering if there is some security setting in chrome that needs to be adjusted? or is it a gcp/google auth setting.

launch.json from vscode for reference:

```
 {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost:4200 for pitch evaluator",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/pitch-evaluator"
    },
```

This used to work; so I can't figure out what changed; but suspect some change in google and chromium security.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this by any chance? I'm facing the same thing right now :/

Answer (score 10):

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497653/how-do-i-properly-setup-vs-code-to-debug-in-chrome-using-an-existing-logged-in)....

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "userDataDir": false    // <----- Note this line
        }
    ]
```

**Note:** Make sure to **close all** Chrome instances

Comment: It's wierd; the original problem randomly went away when i set up a different pc with a fresh build of chrome.   The answer here is useful; but actually answers a different question.   This lets the profile be re used from your 'production' chrome version to the debug; in my question; using google auth under the debugger caused google auth to fail.  Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: This answer worked for me. (re-installing a fresh google chrome did not work for me)

Comment: This worked perfectly in Sept 2023.  Latest React and Chrome.  Following the directions to close all instances of Chrome and relaunch. in debug mode.  I can now use Google Authentication while debugging the react app.

Answer (score 0):

As of **January 2024**, this issue still persist for many and this is the position of Google
[image: Google instructions offering OAuth authentication or migrate to a PWA]

So we should migrate to a PWA or use browser OAuth authentication.
Consider also that "**Less secure apps**" option is gonna be disabled soon (Fall 2024).
Here both links mentioned in the screenshot:

1. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp
2. https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/